# адаптивная ширина video js

Tags: css, reactjs, адаптивная-верстка, videojs

**Video js** (https://videojs.com/) в `options` принимает только статическую ширину плеера, в пикселях
Подскажите, у кого есть опыт, как адаптировать этот плее, сделать его ширину `100%` от ширины контейнера.

Важно!
Без дополнительных функций и костылей, только стилями или пропсами.

Comment: Можно с помощью рефа взять габариты контейнера и задать их плееру, точные пропсы я не помню, потому законсольте их сами.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением класса `vjs-16-9`

```
<video
    ref={ (node) => this.videoNode = node }
    className="video-js vjs-16-9"
/>
```

Теперь размеры видео зависят от ширины контейнера